# nexus5 - how to not update 5.0 and not get notified update

Tags: nexus-5

I don't want to update from 4.4 to 5.0 now, but my phone keep ask to update

How can I not get the update push?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the [Autorun manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun) app is able to disable the update announcement.

This is how it works.

- Enter advanced mode.
- Tick "Show system entries"
- Search for "Google Services Framework"
- Search "System Update Receiver" and disable it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I just tried to install the app you mention but the app said I can't do anything since my phone is not root